# Count loop and report current iteration

Tags: vba, ms-word

So the Word macro I'm making pops up a userform where you enter a quantity x (1 of x) and it duplicates a row based on the quantity entered. The copy paste works fine, but I need to report the number of the copy based on the quantity. So for example, if 4 was entered, then four rows would be created that say "1 of 1", "1 of 2", "1 of 3", and "1 of 4" instead of all four saying "1 of x" when they all get copy pasted. Basically, x=n+1. I'm doing this with a loop, but I can't get this to come out. It will say 1, 1, 1, and 3. I'm trying to figure out how this executes to fix it, so any insight on how this loop is operating would be great! Thanks!

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim tbl As Table
Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)

For i = 0 To Labels2.TextBox3.Value
tbl.Rows(1).Range.Copy
tbl.Rows(2).Range.Paste
i = i + 1

Set myrange = ActiveDocument.Content
myrange.Find.Execute FindText:="1 of " & Labels2.TextBox3.Value, Forward:=True
If myrange.Find.Found = True Then myrange.Text = "1 of " & i

Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're problem is in the fact that you're iterating `i` inside your for loop which already iterates on `i`  If Label2.TextBox3.value is 4 then your loop would only run 3 times because of your `i = i + 1` line.  I don't totally follow your logic but try this

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim tbl As Table
    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)

    For i = 1 To Labels2.TextBox3.Value
        tbl.Rows(1).Range.Copy
        tbl.Rows(2).Range.Paste

        Set myrange = ActiveDocument.Content
        myrange.Find.Execute FindText:="1 of " & Labels2.TextBox3.Value, Forward:=True
        If myrange.Find.Found = True Then myrange.Text = "1 of " & i

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: So my idea was to make all the rows by copying the one in front of it. But I need to change the quantity, the "1 of X". So I thought I could do a Find/Replace loop and label it with i, the loop iteration, but it's not working like that. Your code pops up with repeating 1s then the last one is 2. I watched the macro copy the row, paste it X times, found "1 of " and then changed it to "1 of 1". And since it should be "1 of i", this leads me to believe that it pastes all the rows in one iteration, thus giving an i=1, and then the very last one gets an iteration giving i=2. Is my loop wrong?

Comment: Hey I figured it out. I just made a separate loop for the Find/Replace action. Thanks for the help!